# Fixing Image When Pausing Texts

Tags: beamer, floats, overlays

How can I fix an image while using \pause with texts?

This I what I've done

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Funciones Crecientes y Decrecientes}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

La gráfica que se muestra en la figura-- sube desde $A$ hasta $B$, desciende desde  $B$ hasta $C$,\;\pause y vuelve a subir desde $C$ hasta  $D$.\pause \; Se dice que la función $f$ está creciendo sobre el intervalo $[a, b]$,\pause \; decreciendo sobre    $[b, c]$,\pause \; y creciendo de nuevo sobre $[c, d]$.\pause \; Observe que si $x_{1}$ y $x_{2}$ son dos números cualesquiera entre $a$ y $b$, con $x_{1}<x_{2}$, entonces $f(x_{1})<f(x_{2})$. Use esto como la propiedad que define una función creciente.\pause 


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.5, trim={0 0 0 .5cm}]{cre_decre_func.pdf}%
    \caption{}
   % \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure} 
 
    
\end{frame}%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please format your LaTeX using the tools provided by this site. Also, make sure that your code is compilable *as-is* (Minimal Working Example). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Funciones Crecientes y Decrecientes}
La gráfica que se muestra en la figura-- sube desde $A$ hasta $B$, desciende desde  $B$ hasta $C$,\;
\visible<2->{y vuelve a subir desde $C$ hasta  $D$.\;}
\visible<3->{Se dice que la función $f$ está creciendo sobre el intervalo $[a, b]$,}\;
\visible<4->{decreciendo sobre  $[b, c]$,\;}
\visible<5->{y creciendo de nuevo sobre $[c, d]$.\;}
\visible<6->{Observe que si $x_{1}$ y $x_{2}$ son dos números cualesquiera entre $a$ y $b$, con $x_{1}<x_{2}$, entonces $f(x_{1})<f(x_{2})$. Use esto como la propiedad que define una función creciente.}

\vspace{.25cm}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth, trim={0 0 0 .5cm}]{example-image}
    \caption{Example Image.}
   % \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Beamer frame with overlays and fixed image.]

Comment: Waooo. Thank you so much, buddie. A hug to you!

Comment: @AlcibiadesAbreu If this answer solved your problem, please think about whether you want to accept this answer.